# How to suppress HTTP Connection keep-alive header in response

Tags: openshift, haproxy

I am running a Tomcat webapp with a HAProxy load balancer on Openshift cloud platform, and am wondering how to suppress the 'Connection: Keep-alive' (and an associated 'Keep-alive: timeout=15, max=100') HTTP header being returned from the server with each request. I have tried to change this by making modifications to the HAProxy config file (e.g. setting option httpclose/forceclose), but it seems to have no effect on the mentioned headers.

The reason for trying to suppress the Keep-alive headers is to be able to support potentially hundreds of simultaneous users sending a steady and continuous load of requests to the server. In order to avoid hitting the max number of connections and that a small number of users occupy all connections, and not releasing them in between their requests, I was thinking it is necessary to exclude the Keep-alive header in the responses! Not sure the assumption is correct though.

Thanks in advance for any advise!

Comment: Which version from Openshift cloud platform do you use?

Comment: I'm on Openshift Online v2.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know anything about V2. When do you plan to move to v3